# If $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ is an increasing and continous function such that $f(b)=b$ $f(a)>a$, is it true that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in\langle a,b\rangle$

Tags: functions, continuity, monotone-functions

If $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ is an increasing and continous function such that $f(a)>a$ and $f(b)=b$, is it true that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in\langle a,b\rangle$

Attempt:
I can't seem find the counterexample nor seem to prove it, any hint is welcomed.

Comment: Let $a = 0$ and $b = 1$. Take $f$ to be linear on the interval $[0,1/2]$ and on the interval $[1/2,1]$ such that $f(0) = r$, $f(1/2) = s$ and $f(1) = 1$ for any $r < s < 1/2$. (I guess concretely $f(x) = r + 2(s-r)x$ for $x \leq 1/2$ and $f(x) = 2(1-s)x +1-2(1-s)$

Comment: just take $f$ to be a constant function on $[a,b)$.

Comment: Start with $a=0$, $b=1$, and draw a graph of $g(x)=x$, then try to draw a graph for an increasing function $f$ with $f(0)=3/4$ and $f(1)=1$ that cuts the graph of $g$ in some intermediate point. Something like $f(x)=\frac 34+\frac 14x^2$ maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. Take $f(x)=0.99x^4+0.01$ on $[0,1]$.